# RegEx for extracting numeric patterns

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I got a complex string like this:

```
x <- "Lab ID : 11.11111 4\\nStatus : Final(F)\\nValue : 0.4 %\\nLow range:  0\\nHigh range:  2\\n"
```

The value `0.4` is what's interesting - so always the numeric pattern right after `Value :`

So far I have tried the following:

```
y <- gsub(".*Value : \\s*|\\\\.*", "", x)
```

Followed by :

```
gsub("[^0-9\\.-][^\\s]+", "", y)
```

The challenge is that the numeric pattern can take any positive or negative value and is sometimes followed by more numeric patterns (e.g. `0.4 10E9/ml`). Moreover, it is complicated by the fact that `Value :` can also be followed by character values (e.g. `Value : pending \\nLow ...`

I'm trying to achieve the extraction in one line in a reliable manner.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share more input data?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub` to match the entire string and replace by the pattern that matches the digit value:

```
x <- "Lab ID : 11.11111 4\\nStatus : Final(F)\\nValue : pending -0.4 10E9/ml %\\nLow range:  0\\nHigh range:  2\\n"

sub(".*Value\\s*:[\\s[:alpha:]]*(-?\\d+\\.\\d+).*", "\\1", x, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "-0.4"
```

Note that I have modified the input string to demonstrate that this regex works for all the cases OP has specified.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
regmatches(x, regexpr("Value\\s*:\\s*\\K-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?", x, perl=TRUE))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vZ0XUL/1) and the [R online demo](https://ideone.com/eEcTrT).

**Details**

- `Value`  - a literal substring
- `\s*:\s*` - a colon enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards all text matched so far from the match memory buffer
- `-?` - an optional minus
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional sequence of a dot and 1+ digits.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/snUkj8/1/) would cover all your possible inputs:

```
[0-9\s\.]+%
```

[image]